# How fast could snake-people move

Tags: biology, fantasy-races

Say a snake-person was between fifteen and eighteen feet long on average (this includes the "human" part of the body). That's around the length of an anaconda, but I imagine it would have to be thicker to support the human torso. Given that, how fast could a creature like this move?

Edit: Apparently this needs more details, so below is an example of the kind of creature I'm describing. The type of movement I'm asking about is similar to how a snake slithers, but with a human torso raised off the ground (similar to how snakes rear up). Hope that clears things up.

[image]

---

EDIT:
This creature could be considered a mythological creature called a [Lamia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamia).

Comment: This is vague. Describe which parts of the human are included in snake-people. Do they have feet at the ends? Do they have arms? Do they look like a human version of [Slinky Dog](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Slinky_Dog) from the _Toy Story_ franchise?

Comment: You need to specify what kind of environment (see [flying snakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopelea)) and what kind of movement you are referring to - striking like a coiled cobra, running (we still don't know if they have massive legs and feet) or perhaps rolling like the [cluster-lizards](https://lexx.fandom.com/wiki/Cluster_Lizard) in Lexx (faster than people can run). Voting to close as too broad. (From review).

Comment: Probably second only to panda-people on a steep slope...

Comment: Can you add a little more.  How long is the tail, how tall are they, do they stay upright when moving or drop down like a snake?

Comment: "How fast could snake-people move" Anything lower than lightspeed, if you throw them hard enough

Comment: @Trevor I already said they have their torso raised up when they slither, and their complete length is between fifteen and twenty feet. The human torso is basically the size of an upper human torso. I even gave a picture. How much more information could I possibly give?

Comment: @RichardLindahl The edit is helpful as we now know what you are after. We have many questions about [Lamia](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=lamia) - please enjoy the search facility. Voting to reopen. (From review).

Answer (score 4):

**Not all that fast.**

I"ll assume from context that what you're describing is like a snake-centaur. e.g. a human torso with a snake body extending from the pelvis.

As far as locomotion is concerned, what you're describing is basically just a slightly larger anaconda that has to carry a significant portion of its body mass up off the ground (the human torso).

An [actual anaconda](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJnM2n44jmAhWEoFsKHdHQBZkQFjACegQIDBAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reference.com%2Fpets-animals%2Ffast-anacondas-move-caf38f6073d1aba&usg=AOvVaw3k7GAGS-RYZ5RWajsn8Edl) can do about 5mph on land and 10mph in the water. Your snake person would be a bit slower than that in both cases because the human torso reduces efficiency. Something like 4mph on land and 8mph in the water would be reasonable, which would make it SIGNIFICANTLY slower than a running human (15mph) on land, but much faster than a swimming human (4-5mph).

Comment: How were you confident enough to answer this question? Virtually no information was given. All they specified was the length and that it had a human torso.

Comment: A) He's assuming a snake-centaur body format. B) That's pretty much all you need. 4mph on land seems like a good guess because snake locomotion is pretty simplistic.

Comment: @Halfthawed I mean, it's POSSIBLE that the OP was thinking of some other kind of bodyshape/form of locomotion, but not very likely.

Comment: Yuan-ti *do* come in a surprisingly large variety. But naturally I would also assume the XCOM variant.

Comment: @Halfthawed wait, what's the difference? Snake head, humanoid torso/arms, snake abdomen/tail, same for both of those, isn't it?

Comment: There are also Yuan-ti who have fully humanoid legs, a snake head, and snake arms. It's a weird cult.

Comment: @Halfthawed Huh! Today I Learned.